# SciDraw: Specify ticks for secondary axes / right and top edges of the frame

Tags: ticks, scidraw

I would like to use `SciDraw` to draw my figures and I would like to label the top and right axes of the frame. I guess it should be possible using `FigAxis` or even maybe some equivalent of `XTicks` (I tried `X2ticks` but didn't work). Just the documentation does not seem to be specific enough for me to figure out how it might work.

Example:

[image: plot]

The figure was created using this code:

```
<< "SciDraw`"
test = Figure[
  {FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[DensityPlot[x + y, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 4}]]},
     XPlotRange -> {0, 2},
     YPlotRange -> {0, 4},
     YTickLabelRange -> {0, 4},
     XTickLabelRange -> {0, 2},
     PanelLetter -> None
     ];
   },
  CanvasSize -> {4, 4}]
Export["test.png", test]
```

How can I get the tick labels on the right edge of the frame and ideally even have a label for that axis?

**Update:**

In the documentation it is claimed that regular mathematica plot options would work with `SciDraw`, too, but even then tick labels and axes labels are not shown:

```
test = Figure[
  {FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[DensityPlot[x + y, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 4}]]},
     XPlotRange -> {0, 2},
     YPlotRange -> {0, 4},
     Ticks -> {{None, LinTicks}, {None, None}},
     FrameLabel -> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}},
     PanelLetter -> None
     ];
   },
  CanvasSize -> {4, 4}]
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: Documentation says to use XXFrameLabel and YYFrameLabel, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Also needs `XXShowFrameLabel -> True`, etc.  Or alternatively, `ShowFrameLabel -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, `X` refers to the $x$ axis, `XX` refers to the secondary one.  The same for `Y` and `YY`.

Your syntax

```
FrameLabel -> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}
```

is correct, and so is

```
XFrameLabel -> "a", XXFrameLabel -> "b", ...
```

What's missing is enabling the label on the secondary axes:

```
XXShowFrameLabel -> True
```

or

```
ShowFrameLabel -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}
```

Comment: That's what I was missing. Just for completeness, `XXShowTickLabels->True` is required in addition to show the tick labels.

Answer (score 2):

@Felix: a bit of a necrothread ....

With

```
<< "SciDraw`"
test = Figure[{FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[
       DensityPlot[x + y, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 4}]]}, 
     XPlotRange -> {0, 2}, YPlotRange -> {0, 4},
     ShowFrameLabel -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
     Ticks -> {{None, LinTicks}, {None, None}}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, PanelLetter -> None];}, 
  CanvasSize -> {4, 4}]
```

we have

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there a trick that Szabolcs did not include in his post? I probably missed it.

Comment: @Felix: swings & roundabouts.  The frame lablels can be added as a 4-element list as I've shown. Or they can be added Szabolcs-style, with the same syntax as standard Plot[].